# Aplication in Docker image how to change hostname from localholst to public

Tags: nginx, docker

I just used this docker image `https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox-docker/` but I was not able to figure out how to configure it to work on public hostname/IP?

I was reading documentation and tryed to figure out, but I am stuck.

I found `nginx.conf` and edited `hostname` URL but it dot work.

```
daemon off;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /dev/stderr info;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include              /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type         application/octet-stream;
    sendfile             on;
    tcp_nopush           on;
    keepalive_timeout    65;
    gzip                 on;
    server_tokens        off;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    server {
        listen 11.22.33.44:8080;
        server_name netbox.domain.tld;

    #    listen      8080;
        access_log  off;

        location /static/ {
            alias /opt/netbox/netbox/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://netbox:8001;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be necessary to change anything inside the container. Edit `netbox-docker.override.yml`.

Change

```
- 8000:8080
```

to

```
- '0.0.0.0:8000:8080'
```

This will configure docker to bind the port to all interfaces, not only the loopback interface. The [documentation for this setting is here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports).

Then create the container(s) with `docker-compose up`.

Comment: and should I leave proxy_pass to server host?

Comment: You shouldn't change anything inside the containers. All your changes will be reverted the next time you pull newer images anyway.